# SQL Server - Performance of query while using IN operator when data is huge

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-performance

I have a query which takes in VendorId as the parameter and it should return all the electronic products of that vendor which are in 'Approved' state and also have a valid registry entry.

The problem is many products have RegistryEntry to check if that RegistryEntry of that product is valid i need to check in tblRegistries table with StatusId=2 which means it is a valid key.

The below query works fine, my concern in regarding the performance  by using

```
IN (SELECT RegistryEntry FROM tblRegistries WHERE StatusId = 2)
```

because in prod environment there is lot of data in tblRegistries  table and when i say

```
SELECT RegistryEntry FROM tblRegistries WHERE StatusId = 2
```

it returns hundreds of thousands of records

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Product] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ElectronicProduct] EP
ON P.ProductId = EP.ProductId
WHERE P.VendorId = @VendorId
AND P.[RegistryEntry] IN (SELECT RegistryEntry FROM tblRegistries WHERE StatusId = 2) AND EP.Status = 'Approved'
```

I am looking for some expert suggestions on this if this can be done in a better way using joins or other features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tryed something like this ?

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Product] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ElectronicProduct] EP ON P.ProductId = EP.ProductId
INNER JOIN tblRegistries R ON R.RegistryEntry = P.RegistryEntry AND StatusId = 2
WHERE   P.VendorId = @VendorId
        AND EP.Status = 'Approved'
```

Also adding index on joined fields should improve performance

Comment: Hi Acuao, Thank you for your suggestion i have tried using join and the data was not matching and instead of trying to figure out what the issue was i just used IN operator and its my bad... now when i am looking into it again i found that there are duplicate entries in RegistryEntry table for same product and that is causing duplicates in the query result.......Is there a way  we can get only 1 product in the result set even though there are multiple entries for same product and StatusId=2 ?

Comment: You are in quest on great performances,so i would suggest you at fisrt to remove duplicate data in the table.

If you can't do so, you can use a group by, and maybe having clauses, but it may decrease perfs too

Answer (score 0):

I find exists runs a lot quicker often ...

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Product] P
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ElectronicProduct] EP
ON P.ProductId = EP.ProductId
WHERE P.VendorId = @VendorId
AND EXISTS (
   SELECT RegistryEntry FROM tblRegistries 
   WHERE StatusId = 2 and RegistryEntry = P.[RegistryEntry])
```

Comment: Thank you @Northbank75 , its very helpful as i use IN operator a lot and i will try replacing it with Exists going further.